# Compare to nil and return a bool in Swift

Tags: swift

**UPDATE: This question is no longer a problem after Xcode beta5**

Seems the beta3 release refactored how "nil" is working under the hood but didn't come with enough documentation.

I have this piece of code works fine in beta2:

```
func hasLogin() -> Bool {
    return self.credentail != nil
}
```

But in beta3, I got this error

```
Type 'NativeObject' does not conform to protocol 'NilLiteralConvertible'
```

`self.credential` is an optional value of 'Credential' protocol and implemented by NSObject subclass

```
@objc
protocol Credential: NSObjectProtocol, NSCoding {

}

var credentail: Credential?
```

I could make it work by doing doubled negation like this, but it really looks **ABSURD**

```
func hasLogin() -> Bool {
    return !(!self.credentail)
}
```

So is this a bug in Swift or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: [file a bug report](https://bugreport.apple.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The under-the-covers method that Swift uses to turn non-`Bool` values in booleans for use in `if` statements is the `getLogicValue()` method of the `LogicValue` protocol (which `Optional` implements):

```
func hasLogin() -> Bool {
    return self.credential.getLogicValue()
}
```

Comment: Hopefully that won't turn out to be a private method.

Comment: It won't, although it's not well documented yet. Specifically: The `LogicValue` protocol and its use is mentioned in the language reference (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Statements.html) but as far as I can tell the docs don't yet actually explain what the protocol is.

Comment: The biggest problem I have with Swift at the moment is the lack of documentation.  You are right that the method can't be made private - it would break the mechanics of testing logic values.

Comment: I wonder if you could add an extension to Int to implement LogicValue to give C-like semantics and thus subvert all the good stuff....

Comment: Yeah, that would be pretty trivial. If you look in the headers, you'll see that a lot of Swift's C interoperability types (various pointer types, CString, etc) already do that. And yes, better documentation for Swift would be wonderful. The details you get from command-clicking to see the framework headers help a lot (there's a bunch of code comments in there, too) but it's a steep learning curve to that. But at the same time, the language is still very much a work in progress -- many things are liable to change with each new beta.

Comment: Looks like this is the best solution for now, hope Apple will fix it in beta4.

Answer (score 3):

This was working for me:

```
func hasLogin() -> Bool {
    return self.credential ? true : false
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The release notes of XCode 6 Beta 5 state the following:

> Optionals no longer conform to the BooleanType (formerly LogicValue)
> protocol, so they may no longer be used in place of boolean
> expressions (they must be explicitly compared with v != nil). This
> resolves confusion around Bool? and related types, makes code more
> explicit about what test is expected, and is more consistent with the
> rest of the language.
>
> Note that ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional still includes some BooleanType
> functionality. This !issue will be resolved in a future beta.
> (17110911)!

This means your previous approach should work again:

```
func hasLogin() -> Bool {
    return self.credentail != nil
}
```